# How to fix an error of reading a text file

Tags: c

I have tried to reading a text file but the array stores only the last line of the text file.

```c
    char cleanedText[10000]={'\0'};
    while(!feof(fileptr))
      {
        fgets(cleanedText, 10000 , fileptr);
      }
```

But,the `cleanedText` stores only the last sentence which is written in the text line.

For example these two is written in the text,

`asdasdasd`

`thisisus`

When i print the `cleanedText`.

The screen just shows `thisisus`.

What is the problem?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't output anything. See [mcve].

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) That is mitigated somewhat by your use of `fgets` in the loop, but I suspect you have more than just `fgets` there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `fgets` writes into the same place, overwriting what was there previously.

Comment: (or each call to `fgets` replace what is in `cleanedText`) -- which is what I think you are saying.

Comment: I got it. But, what can be the strategy to store all lines. I mean all text.

Comment: Figure out where to put each new line.  How you do that depends on how you want them stored.